# include application-properties from multiple modules in maven multi-module spring-boot executable jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, executable-jar, multi-module, application.properties

we have a maven multi-module pom project with a core-module where i want to keep common application.properties, like database-access, email-gateways etc. Is it possible to integrate those application*.properties in the executable jar of the other modules as well (jars built by `spring-boot-maven-plugin`)?

when taking a look into the built jar, you can see that only the module's resources are integrated, all other modules are ignored.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at this article: [How to share resources across projects in Maven](https://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/). It's quite old, but still valid for Maven.

Comment: reading this now, thanks! i'm just not too sure how i might integrate this with spring-boot-maven-plugin